# how to find dynamically created table with rows id in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

i created dynamically a table with 3 rows not by using table tag, .... i need to find these rows in scripting...in button click, if any of these rows is empty then need to generate an alert  message like enter current row..... how can i do this...

please suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

I have created a very simplistic example. You can modify it to suite your situation.

```
<html>

  <head>

  <title></title>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  window.onload = function(){

  var button = document.getElementById('row_check');

  var tableDiv = document.getElementById('container');

  var tableHTML = "<div id='mytable'><div id='row_one'>I am not empty</div><div id='row_two'></div><div id='row_three'></div></div>"

  tableDiv.innerHTML = tableHTML; 

  button.onclick = function(){

   if(document.getElementById('row_one').innerHTML == '') alert('Row 1 empty');

   if(document.getElementById('row_two').innerHTML == '') alert('Row 2 empty');

   if(document.getElementById('row_three').innerHTML == '') alert('Row 3 empty');

    }

 }

  </script>

  <style type="text/css">

  #mytable {

    width: 305px;

    height: auto;

    border: 1px solid black;

    padding:5px;  

    margin-top:10px;

  }

  #mytable div{

    width: 290px;

    height: 100px;

    margin:5px;

    border: 1px solid red; 

  }

  </style>

  </head>

  <body>

  <input type="button" value="Check Rows" id="row_check"/>

 <div id="container">  

</div>

  </body>

</html>
```